# Sitecore 6.6 Link Database faulty after update from 6.3

Tags: database, hyperlink, sitecore

After updating a Sitecore 6.3 to 6.6, the link database seems to be faulty. Rebuild Link Database from the Control Panel doesn't help.

Example of an error: In the Content Editor when I click on Navigate -> Links, there are no entries in there for the clicked item although it is definitly linked in other items.

Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: You should be more descriptive. What is the exact issue? Does rebuilding ends with an error or just doesn't help with your issue?

Comment: There's no error when the rebuilding ends, it just doesn't fix the kink database.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the Link Database then ? How you noticed there is a problem ?

Comment: We have a functionality that access the link database. That functionality doesn't work anymore after the update, because the Link DB doesn't seem to deliver the needed information anymore.

Comment: @SpaceJump it might be worth fixing it in more aggressive manner. Create a backup of the core database, trunkate the Links table and Rebuild from the Control Panel.

Comment: @SpaceJump has it worked ? :)

Comment: I'll give it a try later when I have time :)

Comment: Unfortunalety that didn't help. Updated first post with more information.

Comment: Did you rebuild link database for core, master and web?

Comment: Yes, for all 3 databases.